# dev_appserver.py実行時にPython 3 and later is not compatible が出る

Tags: google-cloud

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-debian-ubuntu

Ubuntu14.04の環境で、上記のチュートリアルにしたがってGoogle Cloud SDKのインストールをしました。

目的は、GAEをgoで動かすこと。またその開発をUbuntu14.04上ですることです。

SDKのインストールは特に問題なく進められたのですが、
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/quickstart#test_the_application
こちらの手順の
dev_appserver.py app.yaml

をしようとすると、以下のエラーが出てしまい実行できません。

$python -V
Python 2.7.9
$dev_appserver.py app.yaml
ERROR: Python 3 and later is not compatible with the Google Cloud SDK. Please use Python version 2.7.x.

If you have a compatible Python interpreter installed, you can use it by setting
the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable to point to it.

pythonのデフォルトのバージョンは2.7.9にしたのですが、
別にpython3が入っているために競合しているのかもしれません。
$which python3
/home/ludwig125/.pyenv/shims/python3

エラーの内容にあるとおり、CLOUDSDK_PYTHONをpython2.7にしたのですが、変わりませんでした。
$which python2.7
/usr/local/bin/python2.7
$export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON="/usr/local/bin/python2.7"
↓
これでも同様
ERROR: Python 3 and later is not compatible with the Google Cloud SDK. Please use Python version 2.7.x.

どなたか、解決方法をご教示いただけないでしょうか？

Comment: `python dev_appserver.py app.yaml` を実行するとどうなりますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

`python3`のディレクトリから判断すると`pyenv`を使っているようですが、`pyenv`は、pythonのコマンドをshim実行ファイルで横取りして、どのPythonのバージョンで実行するかを決めるため問題が発生していると思われます。

`pyenv`は、`~/.profile`等に以下のような設定をして`~/.pyenv/bin`へのパスを通すので、`pyenv`を使うとき以外はそれをコメントアウトして`~/.pyenv/bin`へのパスを外すと正常に動作すると思われます。

```
export PYENV_ROOT=\${HOME}/.pyenv
export PATH=\${PYENV_ROOT}/bin:\${PATH}
```

ただし、他にpythonで作成したアプリケーションがあって`pyenv`を使って動いているとそちらに影響が出ますが、Pythonのバージョン管理を副作用の多い`pyenv`を捨てて公式の`pipenv`に変更したほうがいいと思います。

Answer (score -1):

コメントありがとうございます。

[/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/demos/go/helloworld] $python dev_appserver.py app.yaml
/usr/local/bin/python2: can't open file 'dev_appserver.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/demos/go/helloworld] $

/usr/local/bin/python2から dev_appserver.pyが見つからないと出ていますね・・・

（別のマシンから送信したためアイコンが変わっています）

【追記】
パスを指定すれば実行できました改めて記載しておきます。 
python2での実行方法

```
    $python2 /usr/bin/dev_appserver.py app.yaml
```

Comment: @metropolis

以下で実行することができました。
どうもありがとうございました。
$python2 /usr/bin/dev_appserver.py app.yaml

Comment: アイコンが変わっただけではなく、別アカウントとしてログインしている状態です。ヘルプを参照してどちらか一方のアカウントにマージすることを検討してください。 - https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: @hayakawa さん、cubick さんがおっしゃる通りアカウントを統合すると自由にコメントができるようになりますのでご検討ください。また、スタック・オーバーフローでは自己解決した場合[自己回答を推奨しています](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) :) 後から同じ疑問で困った方のためにも、自己回答で回答として投稿して頂けるとありがたいです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 初めて投稿したために諸々分かっておらず申し訳ありません。
Yasuhiro Niji
ありがとうございます。pipenvに移行したいと思います。

cubick
最初に質問した際に投稿したアカウントのプロフィールリンクが取得できないので、マージがすぐにできません。(最初は仮想マシンのUbuntu、今はホストのWindowsで投稿)
後ほど確認できたらやってみたいと思います。

@nekketsuuu
（自己解決したといっていいのか疑問ですが）
上記でいただいたヒントをもとに
パスを指定すれば実行できましたので、私としてはこれで解決としたいと思っています.

改めて記載しておきます。

python2での実行方法
 $python2 /usr/bin/dev_appserver.py app.yaml

Comment: @hayakawa さん、お疲れ様でした :) (1) 最初のアカウントのプロフィールへは、上のほうにあるプロフィール表示の名前からリンクで飛べるようになっています。今回の場合[こちら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/29684/hayakawa)ですね。 (2) 解決法は回答に追記する形にして頂けると、後から来た方からも読みやすいです（コメントは読みにくいです）。回答の下の「編集」から自由に追記できますので、そちらからお願いできますでしょうか？　色々と注文をつけてしまって申し訳ありません。。。